# Finding P-value Fraction from T-test in R

Tags: r, distribution

Given 2 samples of 500 values from the exactly the same normal distribution (with mean 10 and standard deviation 2), I run the t-test 100,000 times:

```
replicate(100,000, (t.test(rnorm(500,10,5), rnorm(500,10,5))))
```

The output is as such:

```
    [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    [50] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    [99] 0 0
```

[edit] If I remove the comma to run it 100000 since apparently it wasn't before, 
it comes out as

```
        [,98011]                                  [,98012]                                 
        [,98013]                                  [,98014]                                 
        [,98015]                                  [,98016]                                 
        [,98017]                                  [,98018]                                 
        [,98019]                                  [,98020]                                 
        [,98021]                                  [,98022]                                 
        [,98023]                                  [,98024]                                 
        [,98025]                                  [,98026]
```

I am a bit confused with these outputs...

How do I now find the fraction of cases where the P-value is lower than 0.05, when it just shows zeros?

Comment: You are only running the test 100 times.  My guess is that you have decimals set to `,`, but I can't reproduce this result.  I get 100 t-tests

Comment: I removed the comma to run it 100000

Comment: @espop23 see my updated answer for a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse my earlier lapse in brainpower (long day). Give this a try.

```
x <- replicate(100000, {
  sample1 <- rnorm(500,10,5);
  sample2 <- rnorm(500,10,5);
  test <- t.test(sample1, sample2);
  test$p.value
})
hist(x)
```

[image]

```
length(x[x < 0.05])/length(x)
[1] 0.04936
```

Comment: @nongkrong - jeez. that's a mistake worthy of public shaming. fixed.

Comment: Is the histogram of the p-values then?

Comment: @espop23 - yes this is a histogram of the p-values.

Comment: Also, I realised I didnt say that the sample is taken 2 times. How does this affect the code?

Comment: @espop23 - It doesn't (you couldn't generate the p-value without two samples) The code example I provided 1) creates 2 samples of with a length of 500, mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 5, 2) runs a t-test on those two samples, 3) repeats the process 100,000 times, 4) returns a vector containing all 100,000 p-values.

Comment: One more question: given the histogram, does that mean the type error I rate is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the comma, you replicate "000" 100 times (IE- the extra code on t-tests is ignored). Since `000 == 0`, the return is a vector of zeros.

When you replicate `t.test(...)` 100000 times, you get the return of `t.test()`, which is a **list**. It appears that you want the p-value from the t-test, not the full object... see `?t.test`

```
sum(replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(500,10,5), rnorm(500,10,5))$p.value) < 0.05)
# or for the fraction
sum(replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(500,10,5), rnorm(500,10,5))$p.value) < 0.05) / 10^5
```

Comment: How can I get a histogram of the pvalues from this? I tried 'hist($p.value)' but it did not work

Comment: your question is extremely vague. what is "this"?

Comment: Sorry, from the result of the fraction (second line of code above)

Comment: Also, I realised that in my question I didnt say that the sample is taken 2 times. How does this affect the code?

Comment: @espop23, a fraction is 1 number. If you want the p-values for each t-test, you need to store them in a vector. This would obviously be easy to get a histogram of. Anything of greater detail requires a clear question (and preferably a reproducible example). I cannot see your workspace, so I have no idea what you're referring to.